# ¿Cómo obtener la plantilla renderizada de django?-pdfkit

Tags: pdf, django-templates

Tengo una plantilla en mi aplicación django y necesito obtenerla en una variable o guardarla en un archivo html.

Mi objetivo es obtener la plantilla renderizada de html a pdf, estoy usando pdfkit ya que es el mejor convertidor html a pdf que he visto, ReportLab no hace lo que yo quiero.

Cuando trato de hacer algo como esto:

```
pdf = pdfkit.from_file('app/templates/app/table.html', 'table.pdf')
```

Obtengo el pdf pero imprimo algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Agradezco cualquier ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la solución a mi caso que uso django 2.0.1 y pdfkit 0.6.1:

Para obtener el template:

```
template = get_template('plapp/person_list.html')
```

Para renderizarlo con los datos:

```
html = template.render({'persons':persons})
```

A continiación la definicion del metodo en views.py, el que descarga el pdf directamente en el navegador:

```
def pdf(request):
    persons = Person.objects.all()
    template = get_template('plapp/person_list.html')
    html = template.render({'persons': persons})
    options = {
       'page-size': 'Letter',
       'encoding': "UTF-8",
   }
   pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, options)
   response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;
   filename="pperson_list_pdf.pdf"'
   return response
```